# Need to extract elevation information from the .tif file using the coordinates (x,y) from .net xml file created using SUMO

Tags: python, xml, google-elevation-api

I am working with .net xml file that has information regarding lanes, roads, junctions of a place and  it has one attribute named Shape - from this I have to extracted x and y coordinates which are in meters.

Now I should use these two coordinates and find the elevation information from the DGM1(Digital terrain model 1) folder which has bunch of .tif files.

My approach :
I was able to extract the x and y coordinates from the .net xml file but the problem is with the transformation of these coordinates to pixel coordinates. When I try to use the transformed pixel coordinates for extracting elevation information I get the error as "raster is out of bounds".

***The transformation parameters I used for the conversion of x,y coordinates to pixel coordinates :***

1. Pixel Width: 1.0
2. Rotation 1: 0.0
3. Rotation 2: 0.0
4. Pixel Height: -1.0
5. Easting of Upper-Left Corner: 462000.5
6. Northing of Upper-Left Corner: 5548999.5

Dataset Information: Width: 1000 Height: 1000 Number of Bands: 1 Coordinate Reference System (CRS): EPSG:25832
**Bounding Box**: BoundingBox(left=462000.0, bottom=5548000.0, right=463000.0, top=5549000.0) Data Type: float32

Formula I used for conversion :

**For X coordinate:**

```
X offset = X coordinate − Easting of Upper-Left Corner 

**For Y coordinate:**
Y offset = Northing of Upper-Left Corner − Y coordinate

X offset = 312.37−462000.5= **−461688.13**
Y offset =5548999.5−1176.31= **5547823.19**

**Pixel X coordinate:** 
X pixel = X offset/Pixel Width

**​Pixel y coordinate:**    
y pixel = y offset/Absolute Pixel Height

X pixel= −461688.13/1.0 = −461688.13
Y pixel= 5547823.19/1.0 = 5547823.19
```

But the transformed pixel coordinates are out of raster bounds, can someone help.. ?> Not sure where I am doing wrong but I am assuming there is something wrong with the transformation only.

The code I used :

@mzjn -

normal python code to extract the x and y coordinates from .net xml file, after extracting them I'm using the below code for transformation and extraction of elevation information from .tif file.

```
    # Read the TIF file for elevation data
    with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
        # Read elevation data
        elev_data = src.read(1)  # Assuming single-band elevation data

        # Read the TFW file for georeferencing information
        with open(tfw_file, 'r') as tfw:
            lines = tfw.readlines()
            # Extract georeferencing parameters from the TFW file
            pixel_width = float(lines[0])
            pixel_height = float(lines[3])
            x_coord = float(lines[4])
            y_coord = float(lines[5])

            # Compute the x and y coordinates in the raster
            col = int((x - x_coord) / pixel_width)
            row = int((y_coord - y) / pixel_height)
           # print (col, row)

            # Check if the coordinates are within the raster bounds
            if 0 <= row < src.height and 0 <= col < src.width:
                elevation = elev_data[row, col]
                return elevation
```

return None  # Return None if coordinates are not found in any file

​

​

Comment: How are you scaling pixels to meters?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jdweng - I'm using  transformation matrix, typically a 3x3 matrix, consists of elements that define scaling, rotation, and translation from pixel space to geographic coordinates 

e.g. :  Transform: | 1.00, 0.00, 462000.00|
           | 0.00,-1.00, 5549000.00|
           | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|

Comment: Looks like you have GPS coordinates where latitude goes from -90 to +90  and longitude goes from -180 to +180.  X is longitude where 180 is  5549000.00,  Y is latitude where 90 = 462000